# regex oracle database version

Tags: regex

I need help to only find the version number in a set of words like "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production". 
I need to run a regex to ONLY find "11.2" in this string of words

Comment: Is it possible for the "11g" to look like the thing you want, but not be it?

Comment: Are you doing this in PL/SQL or another language?

Answer (score 0):

Find the first match of `\d+\.\d+`.